# How do I access a parse tree created by XML::Parser?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a array reference which has some number of array references inside it. The nested array references also contains the array references.  (This is the [tree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Parser#Tree) style of [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Parser).)

```
my $Filename = "sample.xml";

my $Parser = new XML::Parser( Style => 'tree' );

my $Tree = $Parser->parsefile( $Filename );
```

Here the `$Tree` is the array reference it will be array reference , the contents and the nested depth all depends on the xml file. I want to traverse through the nested array `$Tree` and print the contents.

Comment: can you include your sample file or some piece of text of it.

Comment: It simply a xml file.can try with any xml file.

Comment: You should use `XML::Parser->new( Style => 'tree' )` instead of `new XML::Parser( Style => 'tree' )`.  Indirect object syntax can lead to weird bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simplistic version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub printElement
{
  my ($tag, $content) = @_;

  if (ref $content) {
    # This is a XML element:
    my $attrHash = $content->[0];

    print "<$tag>";           # I'm ignoring attributes

    for (my $i = 1; $i < $#$content; $i += 2) {
      printElement(@$content[$i, $i+1]);
    }

    print "</$tag>";
  } else {
    # This is a text pseudo-element:
    print $content;             # I'm not encoding entities
  }
} # end printElement

sub printTree
{
  # The root tree is always a 2-element array
  # of the root element and its content:
  printElement(@{ shift @_ });
  print "\n";
}

# Example parse tree from XML::Parser:
my $tree =
    ['foo', [{}, 'head', [{id => "a"}, 0, "Hello ",  'em', [{}, 0, "there"]],
             'bar', [ {}, 0, "Howdy",  'ref', [{}]],
             0, "do"
            ]
    ];

printTree($tree);
```

This doesn't print attributes, although you could access them through `$attrHash`.  It also doesn't encode entities in the text, so the resulting output is probably not going to be well-formed XML.  I'm leaving those as exercises for the reader. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Data::Walk](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Walk) might be what you're looking for. You can also do that manually with [Universal](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?UNIVERSAL).